# Insert extra row in a loop if a specific requirement is met

Tags: excel, vba

Quite new to programming in general and especially in VBA. I am trying to build a code that adds a blank row if a specific requirement is met in a cell i.e. if a cell in column B is blank. My data input varies in size so cannot define a specific range I suppose.

The data looks like this:

[image]

So far my code looks like this but this it only adds blank rows in the top as soon as column b is empty.

```
For i = 1 To k
  If out.Range("B16").Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
   out.Rows(i).Insert shift:=xlShiftUp
End If
Next i
```

What my code basically does is that it adds a bunch of lines up top atm so it moves the table 6-7 rows down.

Comment: Quite confusing using relative references, and your `i` is absolute so needs to be relative to 16.

Comment: @urdearboy `Range("B16").Range("A1")` is just `Range("B16")`.

Comment: Sorry guys.

What I would like to do is to add a blank row above line 20, 22, 23 and 24 for this table.

Do you have any idea how I should code it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the table data like this: 
[image]

Need to insert entire row if a cell in column B is blank.
So the table become something like this :

[image]

The code:

```
Sub test123()
Set x = Range("B16")
Do Until x.Offset(1, 0).End(xlToRight).Value = "" And x.Offset(1, 0).End(xlToLeft).Value = ""
If x.Value = "" Then
If x.End(xlToRight).Value <> "" Or x.End(xlToLeft).Value <> "" Then
x.EntireRow.Insert
'x.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.Color = vbGreen
End If
End If
Set x = x.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
End Sub
```

The condition to insert entire row are :
 1. if there is a blank cell in column B
 2. to the end-left or to the end-right of this blank cell has value.
The code will stop if to the end-left and to the end-right of this blank cell has no value

That's if I'm not mistaken to get what you mean.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! I've now managed to fix it thanks to you! :) Cheers!